# TypeScript - Using predefined names for custom class names

Tags: typescript, naming

Can we use predefined names from TypeScript for naming custom classes/interfaces?
Can there be a use case that can lead to an error if a custom class name conflicts with a predefined name from TypeScript?

For example - Can I create a custom class called RequestInfo while TypeScript already has a RequestInfo type -> `type RequestInfo = Request | string;`?

Comment: When I was using Discord.js with Typescript I had errors about custom types, When Discord,js custom TYpe was for example `GuildMember` I was passing in Variable Type as `GuildMember | undefined | null` I was getting error that `"GuildMember isn't assignable to Type undefined` and `"GuildMember isn't assignable to Type null` that was weird because I already had passed all of the types what I was getting in errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any predefined name from TypeScript as a custom class/interface/type. The reason being is that a class declaration creates a [constructor function as well as a type definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface). That means I can do something like this:

```
class Hero {}
const myHero: Hero = new Hero();
const somethingElse: Hero & string = '';
```

Therefore, the TypeScript compiler issues an error, when you try to redefine a predefined type because a type is in general generated for a class.

However, if you want to have more than one interface declaration within your module, TypeScript will use the [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) concept which just merges both interfaces into one.

```
interface Hero { x!: number; }
interface Hero { y!: number; }
```

Comment: Thank you @FloWy!

What are your thoughts on using namespace to evade this compile time issue something like? 
```
namespace Test{
 class String{
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah sure. A valid way would be to use namespaces. But personally, I would not really recommend it. Namespaces are just there for organizing your code. In addition, if you use modules as well, it is bad practice to use namespaces at the same time.

Comment: class String{} prompts the `Duplicate Identifier` error. However, adding an export keyword that is export class String{} removes this error. Is this expected?

Comment: I do not have any error with the declaration of a `String` class.